# MySQL PHP - Compare String Date

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a problem comparing my date column to the current date. My Date column is a `String ('13.12.2013 17:12 - Fr.')`. I cannot make it a date field, cause it is only given as a String in Joomla Datetime picker.

I have to select all rows with the date > current date. I've tried some solutions, but nothing works. My current solution is as followed, but it still shows all rows, not only the ones where date > current date.

```
SELECT * FROM jtmpl2_chronoforms_data_test_reservierung 
WHERE res_bestaetigt = 'yes' AND res_deleted = 0 
    AND STR_TO_DATE(res_date, '%d.%m.%Y') > DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%d.%m.%Y') 
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(res_date, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%i') ASC"
```

Can anyone help please?

Comment: I'd recommend posting a question about "how to store Joomla Datetime picker result in a MySQL DATETIME column". Requirements (in this case the requirement that you have a DATETIME value) should determine your data types. The front end should *never* dictate your data type.

Comment: The problem is, I need it exactly as I mentioned, '13.12.2013 17:12 - Fr.'. date, time and day of the week. Or is there any solution to save it like this in a datetime col?

Comment: you can change the date format in the language's ini file..

Comment: Is there no other solution? Because ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(`res_date`, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%i') ASC is also working, so I think there has to be a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your `DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%d.%m.%Y')` is coming out differently than the `STR_TO_DATE(res_date, '%d.%m.%Y')` piece, thus failing comparison. Have a look

```
mysql> select DATE(STR_TO_DATE('13.12.2013 17:12 - Fr.', '%d.%m.%Y'));
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| DATE(STR_TO_DATE('13.12.2013 17:12 - Fr.', '%d.%m.%Y')) |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| 2013-12-13                                              |
+---------------------------------------------------------+

mysql> select DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%d.%m.%Y');
+------------------------------------+
| DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%d.%m.%Y') |
+------------------------------------+
| 16.12.2013                         |
+------------------------------------+
```

Try using `NOW()` for the later piece

```
mysql> select DATE(NOW());
+-------------+
| DATE(NOW()) |
+-------------+
| 2013-12-16  |
+-------------+
```

then the comparison works fine

```
mysql> select DATE(STR_TO_DATE('13.12.2013 17:12 - Fr.', '%d.%m.%Y')) > DATE(NOW());
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| DATE(STR_TO_DATE('13.12.2013 17:12 - Fr.', '%d.%m.%Y')) > NOW() |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                               0 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> select DATE(STR_TO_DATE('13.12.2013 17:12 - Fr.', '%d.%m.%Y')) < DATE(NOW());
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| DATE(STR_TO_DATE('13.12.2013 17:12 - Fr.', '%d.%m.%Y')) < NOW() |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                               1 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: '> NOW() - interval 1 day' works here. Problem solved, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are doing 2 opposing things with 
`STR_TO_DATE(res_date, '%d.%m.%Y') > DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%d.%m.%Y')`

The first part creates a mysql DateTime value, which is what you want.
The secont part creates a string out of a DataTime value.
So you are comparing a datetime vs. a string. Change it the following way:
`STR_TO_DATE(res_date, '%d.%m.%Y') > CURDATE()`

You probably also have to move this condition to the "HAVING" part.

Comment: Why would they need to move the condition to a HAVING clause?